# What's the Pythonic way of getting rid of this loop when iterating a dictionary to modify a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
#replacing each country in dicts's keys with the corresponding dicts value
dicts = {"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
         "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
         "Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}

for old_name, new_name in dicts.items():
    GDP['Country'].replace({old_name : new_name}, inplace = True)
```

The purpose of this code is to rename the following list of countries:

"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
"Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
"Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"

These country names are in the 'Country' column of a GDP pandas dataframe

The code is correct but the for loop is bothering me.

Comment: Or rather just `GDP['Country'].replace(dicts, inplace=True)` should work, I think...

Comment: This worked, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just take out the loop entirely:

```
#replacing each country in dicts's keys with the corresponding dicts value
dicts = {"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
         "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
         "Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}

GDP['Country'].replace(dicts, inplace = True)
```

Since replace takes a dict, it will already do what you're trying to do, i.e. if it matches any key, it will replace it with the corresponding value.